# How to recover the database with old data?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I have 4 database servers.  Each server has same database and same schema. Mistakenly I restored the database util05db backup onto the util01db database.

How can I get the util01db before restored?

Comment: Unless you have a backup of util01db, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I dont have util01db backup,that is why i am worried.

Comment: Then you're screwed and you now know why it's vital to have a good backup strategy.

Comment: If you don't have a backup, the data wasn't apparently that important.

Comment: The data is important,but i mistakenly restored it instead of doing it on other,for the other one, i have backup

Answer (score 1):

if you have a base backup AND full WAL archives you can use point in time recovery.  Otherwise you are stuck.  good luck.  I hope you have something you can work with.

Otherwise you are screwed.  There is no way to roll back restoring a backup in this way.  If you didn't drop relations in the process you *MIGHT* be able to sort things out using min_xid columns on the tables.  In that case you will have a lot of work.....